# SetTimeout delay not working as expected in jquery slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code....
http://jsfiddle.net/KQ8gW/
In this i have placed my setTimeout to 1 min but the function is called much before that.Why is it so????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the function immediately, not passing a reference to the function and you are repeatedly setting the interval.  So, what you're passing to `setInterval()` is the return value from executing `Slide(c,n)`, not a function that will be called later.  Thus it gets called immediately and only once.

To fix it, change this:

```
setInterval(Slide(c,n),60000);
```

to this:

```
setTimeout(function() {Slide(c,n)},60000);
```

---

If this were my code, I wouldn't even use a timer - I'd use the animation completion function like this:

```
var n = $("#slideShow div img").length;
var c = 0;
Slide(c,n);

function Slide(c,n){
    c = ++c % n;
    $("#slideShow div").animate(
        {left:-500*c}, 
        3000, 
        function() {Slide(c,n)}
    );
}​
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/nykd3/

Comment: i tried using setTimeout but still its not working.....http://jsfiddle.net/hCZ8b/1/

Comment: @jade - Did you read my answer at all?  I show you what else you have to fix. My suggestion would be my last implementation which doesn't even use a timer.

Answer (score 0):

You have set an interval, not a timeout. Try using `setTimeout(function, time)`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling an interval inside an interval inside an interval.... etc.

You run the function regularly every minute, and everytime the function runs you set a new interval, looping until infinty and beyond.

Place the interval outside the function, and call it with a function to avoid eval'ing, like so:

```
var n = $("#slideShow div img").length, c = 0;

Slide(c, n);
setInterval(function() { Slide(c, n); }, 60000);

function Slide(c, n) {
    c = ++c % n;
    $("#slideShow div").animate({
        left: -500 * c
    }, 7000);
}​
```

Comment: this not working since the values should be reset each time the function is called for image to slide,